# HAML meta-programming

Tags: metaprogramming, haml

Let's say I want to render the following

```
<div id="foo" class="foo">
  Bar
</div>
```

In HAML, I'd typically write

```
#foo.foo Bar
```

Is there an easy way to do something like the following?

```
#foo{ :class => id_for_this_tag }
```

What I really want is the ability to hook into the markup generation of HAML to clean up some views.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example should work as is. The following line:

```
#foo{:class => @my_class }
```

Will generate the following HTML:

```
<div class='foobar' id='foo'></div>
```

Assuming that `@my_class = "foobar"` is defined appropriately.

I'm not aware of any way to trim it any further, but you can get away with anything using this format. For example:

```
- bob = "silly"
#foo{:class => bob, :summary => "whatever", :arbitrary => "arbitrary"}
```

Generates:

```
<div arbitrary='arbitrary' class='silly' id='foo' summary='whatever'>
```

Comment: I want to do this without explicitly setting @my_class.  I want a way to introspect the HTML element being built by HAML and get at its properties.